# tikz: Bigger arrowheads, merging lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, arrows

I'm trying to add arrows between equations using `TikZ` and I'm having some issues.

First, I can't figure out how to make the lines thicker and the arrowheads bigger.

Second, I can't figure out how to get lines coming out of two different nodes that merge to form an arrow pointing at a third node. Here is some code showing the basic layout, followed by an image showing where I'm at with the code at this point (I want the red lines all merged). Some of the images at [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48606/merge-arrows-with-tikz) show what I want quite nicely, but I can't figure out how to apply that stuff to my situation.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Block title goes here}                        

Some text here.

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        % \draw[style=help lines] (-1cm,0cm) grid[step=1cm] (5cm,5cm); % These don't work for some reason.
            \node (e0) at (2, 0.0) {$p_{a,i} + p_{n,i} = 1$} ;
            \node (e1) at (2, -0.5) {$E_i = p_{a,i}*\overline{F_a} + (1 - p_{a,i})*\overline{F_n}$} ;
            \node (e2) at (2, -1.0) {$S = \sum^N_{i=1}(E_i - D_i)^2$} ;
            \node (e3) at (1, -2.0) {$\frac{\partial S}{\partial \overline{F_n}} = 0$} ;
            \node (e4) at (1, -4.0) {$\overline{F_a} = \frac{\overline{D}}{\overline{p_a}} + (1 - \frac{1}{\overline{p_a}})\overline{F_n}$} ;
            \node (e5) at (6, -2.0) {$\frac{\partial S}{\partial \overline{F_a}} = 0$} ;
            \node (e6) at (6, -5.0) {$\overline{F_n} = \overline{D} - \frac{covariance(p_a,D)}{variance(p_a)}\overline{p_a}$} ;

        \node (n1) at (5, -4.0) {} ;

        \draw[->] (e2) to (e3) ;
        \draw[->] (e2) to (e5) ;
        \draw[->] (e3) to (e4) ;
        \draw[] (e4) to (n1) ;
        \draw[] (e5) to (n1) ;
        \draw[->] (n1) to (e6) ;

        \end{tikzpicture}       

\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: image 1]

EDIT Apr. 11 at 7:10 pm EDT: Changed code to more clearly illustrate the problem, and to reflect changes made after reading [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48606/merge-arrows-with-tikz).

Comment: You can check the manual for the options `[remember picture,overlay]` and increase the `[linewidth=X mm]`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your problem is not how to draw lines between nodes defined in different `tikzpicture`s, but how to draw the merged line, right? In that case, maybe you should reduce your example to one that doesn't use different `tikzpicture`s, since it distracts from your actual issue.

Comment: Also do these examples in this question [merge-arrows-with-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48606/merge-arrows-with-tikz) help?

Comment: @percusse : Setting `\pgfsetlinewidth{5pt}` within the `tikzpicture` in question helped with the line thickness and arrowhead size issues, thanks!

Comment: @SamRabin: Instead of using the low level `\pgfsetlinewidth`, you can use the TikZ key `line width=<width>` in the options of your `\draw` command (so `\draw [line width=3pt] (e2) to [out=-90, in=180] (e6);`, for example).

Comment: Okay, the suggestions in that thread got me a lot of the way there… And now I actually understand what you were talking about, @Jake, with the single vs. different `tikzpictures`. Yes, my question is about how to draw a merged line, whether that's within one `tikzpicture` or between multiple ones. I added some new code to reflect that, and my progress due to the thread.

Comment: The immediate fix is `\coordinate (n1) at (5, -4.0);` instead of a node. That would remove that node whitespace. Do you still want to merge them with bent arrows? Because then you want to curve to `n1` from two sources and then `\draw` to the target `e6`

Answer (score 14):

It's a good idea to define an auxiliary point where the arrows will meet. Instead of using a `node`, it's better to use a `\coordinate (<name>) at (<location>);`. That saves you the trouble of defining an empty node text using `{}`, and it will make the joining of the lines easier, since a `coordinate` (which is just shorthand for `\node [coordinate] (<name>) at (<location>) {};`) doesn't take up space.

To get curved lines, you can use the `in=<angle>` and `out=<angle>` options of the `to` paths. Make sure that both `to` paths that go into the auxiliary node have the same `in` angle, and that the `to` path leaving the auxiliary node has that `<angle + 180>` as the `out` angle. That way, the lines will join up smoothly.

To save yourself some typing with common options, you can use a `\begin{scope}[<options>] ... \end{scope}`, the `<options>` will apply to all commands within the scope. For example, you could use a `scope` with the options `very thick, -stealth` to get thick lines with `stealth` arrow tips. To switch off the arrow tips for some lines, you can pass the option `-` to those lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Block title goes here}                        

Some text here.

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        % \draw[style=help lines] (-1cm,0cm) grid[step=1cm] (5cm,5cm); % These don't work for some reason.
            \node (e0) at (2, 0.0) {$p_{a,i} + p_{n,i} = 1$} ;
            \node (e1) at (2, -0.5) {$E_i = p_{a,i}*\overline{F_a} + (1 - p_{a,i})*\overline{F_n}$} ;
            \node (e2) at (2, -1.0) {$S = \sum^N_{i=1}(E_i - D_i)^2$} ;
            \node (e3) at (1, -2.0) {$\frac{\partial S}{\partial \overline{F_n}} = 0$} ;
            \node (e4) at (1, -4.0) {$\overline{F_a} = \frac{\overline{D}}{\overline{p_a}} + (1 - \frac{1}{\overline{p_a}})\overline{F_n}$} ;
            \node (e5) at (6, -2.0) {$\frac{\partial S}{\partial \overline{F_a}} = 0$} ;
            \node (e6) at (6, -5.0) {$\overline{F_n} = \overline{D} - \frac{covariance(p_a,D)}{variance(p_a)}\overline{p_a}$} ;

        \coordinate (n1) at (5.2, -4.2);
        \begin{scope}[very thick, -stealth]
        \draw (e2) to (e3) ;
        \draw (e2) to (e5) ;
        \draw (e3) to (e4) ;
        \draw[-] (e4) to [in=135, out=0] (n1) ;
        \draw[-] (e5) to [in=135, out=-90] (n1) ;
        \draw (n1) to [out=-45] (e6) ;
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}       

\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```