# How to join two arrows with (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge arrows with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48606/merge-arrows-with-tikz)

Is there a way to join two arrows? They should start from two different nodes, join and point to a third node. That would be great!

here I have a minimal example:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=ellipse];
        \node (node1) at (150:3) {x};
        \node (node2) at ( 30:3) {y};
        \node (node3) at ( 270:0) {z};

        \path[->] (node1) edge [out=-20, in=100,draw=gruen,line width=2pt] (30:1);
        \path[->] (node2) edge [out=200, in=80] (node3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I can try until I have an approximate coordinate where the join happens, but that would be a problem if I want to change the position of the nodes later.

**EDIT**

I would like to have it that way:

```
X ------             -------> Z
Y ------/
```

Not the best sketch. But as percusse mentioned, the linked question should answer my question, too.

Comment: How do you want to proceed after join happens? Currently the line specs are different. You can use a temporary coordinate relative the target node for example at `($(node3)!1.5!(node3.70)$)` and use it as a joining point.

Comment: Also related [Merge arrows with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48606/3235)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to percusse! I didn't find that question .. here is what my solution now looks like:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=ellipse];
        \node (node1) at (150:3) {x};
        \node (node2) at ( 30:3) {y};
        \node (node3) at ( 270:0) {z};

        \coordinate (zJoin) at ([yshift=0.5cm]node3.north);
        \draw[->] (zJoin) -- (node3); % the arrow

        \path (node1) edge [out=-20, in=100,draw=gruen,line width=2pt] (zJoin);
        \path (node2) edge [out=200, in=80] (zJoin);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: No problem! Now that it is solved I've voted as a duplicate to the other linked question.

Answer (score 2):

You can select a specific point in a node where both arrows will join.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=ellipse];
        \node (node1) at (150:3) {x};
        \node (node2) at ( 30:3) {y};
        \node (node3) at ( 270:0) {z};

        \path[->] (node1) edge [out=-20, in=100,draw=green,line width=2pt] (node3.north);
        \path[->] (node2) edge [out=200, in=80] (node3.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I forgot to mention that I would like to join before they reach the target.